# How can I increase the size of volume var/lib/docker/overlay2 or mounted to a new Virtual Disk in a Debian VM

Tags: docker, debian, docker-volume

I have a Docker CE installed on a Debian 9 VM,
The issue I am facing is that the free size at var/lib/docker/overlay2 is limited by default and it's not enough to install more than 2 containers.

I try prune but it's not enough.

Can I increase the size of var/lib/docker/overlay2 or mount a new Virtual Disk at the VM and change the var/lib/docker/overlay2 to point the new disk?

I try prune but didn't work.
I don't know how to change the var mount point size during the installation of the Debian in the VM in order to increase the size before installing the Debian CE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the easiest way is to use onther root directory:

change the path in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` to :

```
{
“data-root”: "/new/path"
}
```

and then restart your Docker service.

**PS**: you need to move the data from /var/lib/docker to the new location if you want to use old images, containers .... otherwise all of the data will gone.